# On Form Submit Everything Is Set But Not Updating Values On Page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I've been racking my brain all day with this issue. On my page I have a sub-user area that I'm creating for a uni project, where an admin can create three sub-users. The functionality of all this works perfectly however, I wanted to implement a alert/dialog system where if the user was to rename one of their sub-users and the name was already taken by one of the other two an alert/dialog would pop up or the same thing to inform that the save has been made. In theory it works fine however the issue is when I make the save the dialog pops up with the saved message, I then close it and the username hasn't updated on the page. Yet in my directory it has updated perfectly. It isn't till I refresh the page that it updates. If someone could clear this annoying issue up for me that would be incredible and most appropriated.

Thanks again,
Matt.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var msg = '<?php echo $msg; ?>';

  $(function() {
    $("#dialog1").dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      show: {
        effect: "puff",
        duration: 300
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "clip",
        duration: 500
      }
    });

    if (msg == '01') {
      $("#dialog1").dialog("open");
    }

    $("#opener").on("click", function() {
      $("#dialog1").dialog("open");
    });

  });

  $(function() {
    $("#dialog2").dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      show: {
        effect: "puff",
        duration: 300
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "clip",
        duration: 500
      }
    });

    if (msg == '02') {
      $("#dialog2").dialog("open");
    }

    $("#opener").on("click", function() {
      $("#dialog2").dialog("open");
    });

  });

  $(function() {
    $("#dialog3").dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      show: {
        effect: "puff",
        duration: 300
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "clip",
        duration: 500
      }
    });

    if (msg == '03') {
      $("#dialog3").dialog("open");
    }

    $("#opener").on("click", function() {
      $("#dialog3").dialog("open");
    });

  });

  $(function() {
    $("#dialog4").dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      show: {
        effect: "puff",
        duration: 300
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "clip",
        duration: 500
      }
    });

    if (msg == '04') {
      $("#dialog4").dialog("open");
    }

    $("#opener").on("click", function() {
      $("#dialog4").dialog("open");
    });

  });
}); < /script>
```

```css
.SettingsTable {
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-color: #4C66A4;
}
.UsernameTitle {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #ddebf7;
}
.btnSupport2 {
  margin-left: 35%;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #ddebf7;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #ddebf7;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<table width="90%" class="SettingsTable" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="UsernameTitle">No.1
      <? echo $Username ?>-
      <? if($savedS1A1=='' ){echo 'Sub-User';}else{echo $savedS1A1;} ?>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p align="center">Username:</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="S1A1" type="text" value="<? echo $savedS1A1 ?>">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p align="center">Password:</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="S1A2" type="text" value="<? echo $savedS1A2 ?>">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="81" colspan="2">
      <input name="Save" type="submit" value="Save" class="btnSupport2">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){  
    $S1A1 = $_POST['S1A1']; 
    $S1A2 = $_POST['S1A2']; 

    $S2A1 = $_POST['S2A1']; 
    $S2A2 = $_POST['S2A2']; 

    $S3A1 = $_POST['S3A1']; 
    $S3A2 = $_POST['S3A2'];



    if(($S1A1 !== $S2A1) and ($S1A1 !== $S3A1)){
        if(is_dir("USERS/$Username-$savedS1A1") && !is_dir("USERS/$Username-$S1A1")){
            rename("USERS/$Username-$savedS1A1" , "USERS/$Username-$S1A1");

            $myFile=fopen("USERS/".$Username."-".$S1A1."/Password.txt","w") or exit("Can’t open file!");
            fwrite($myFile, $S1A2);
            fclose($myFile);

            $myFile=fopen("USERS/".$Username."/Sub-Users/No1/Username.txt","w") or exit("Can’t open file!");
            fwrite($myFile, $S1A1);
            fclose($myFile);

            $myFile=fopen("USERS/".$Username."/Sub-Users/No1/Password.txt","w") or exit("Can’t open file!");
            fwrite($myFile, $S1A2);
            fclose($myFile);
        }
        else{
            $myFile=fopen("USERS/".$Username."-".$savedS1A1."/Password.txt","w") or exit("Can’t open file!");
            fwrite($myFile, $S1A2);
            fclose($myFile);    

            $myFile=fopen("USERS/".$Username."/Sub-Users/No1/Password.txt","w") or exit("Can’t open file!");
            fwrite($myFile, $S1A2);
            fclose($myFile);
        }
    }

    if(($S2A1 !== $S1A1) and ($S2A1 !== $S3A1)){
        if(is_dir("USERS/$Username-$savedS2A1") && !is_dir("USERS/$Username-$S2A1")){
            rename("USERS/$Username-$savedS2A1" , "USERS/$Username-$S2A1");

            $myFile=fopen("USERS/".$Username."-".$S2A1."/Password.txt","w") or exit("Can’t open file!");
            fwrite($myFile, $S2A2);
            fclose($myFile);

            $myFile=fopen("USERS/".$Username."/Sub-Users/No2/Username.txt","w") or exit("Can’t open file!");
            fwrite($myFile, $S2A1);
            fclose($myFile);

            $myFile=fopen("USERS/".$Username."/Sub-Users/No2/Password.txt","w") or exit("Can’t open file!");
            fwrite($myFile, $S2A2);
            fclose($myFile);
            }
        else{
            $myFile=fopen("USERS/".$Username."-".$savedS2A1."/Password.txt","w") or exit("Can’t open file!");
            fwrite($myFile, $S2A2);
            fclose($myFile);    

            $myFile=fopen("USERS/".$Username."/Sub-Users/No2/Password.txt","w") or exit("Can’t open file!");
            fwrite($myFile, $S2A2);
            fclose($myFile);
        }           
    }

    if(($S3A1 !== $S1A1) and ($S3A1 !== $S2A1)){
        if(is_dir("USERS/$Username-$savedS3A1") && !is_dir("USERS/$Username-$S3A1")){
            rename("USERS/$Username-$savedS3A1" , "USERS/$Username-$S3A1");

            $myFile=fopen("USERS/".$Username."-".$S3A1."/Password.txt","w") or exit("Can’t open file!");
            fwrite($myFile, $S3A2);
            fclose($myFile);

            $myFile=fopen("USERS/".$Username."/Sub-Users/No3/Username.txt","w") or exit("Can’t open file!");
            fwrite($myFile, $S3A1);
            fclose($myFile);

            $myFile=fopen("USERS/".$Username."/Sub-Users/No3/Password.txt","w") or exit("Can’t open file!");
            fwrite($myFile, $S3A2);
            fclose($myFile);
        }
        else{
            $myFile=fopen("USERS/".$Username."-".$savedS3A1."/Password.txt","w") or exit("Can’t open file!");
            fwrite($myFile, $S3A2);
            fclose($myFile);    

            $myFile=fopen("USERS/".$Username."/Sub-Users/No3/Password.txt","w") or exit("Can’t open file!");
            fwrite($myFile, $S3A2);
            fclose($myFile);
        }
    }

    if($S1A1 == $S2A1){
        $msg = '01';
    }
    if($S1A1 == $S3A1){
        $msg = '02';    
    }
    if($S3A1 == $S2A1){
        $msg = '03';    
    }
    if(($S1A1 !== $S2A1) and ($S1A1 !== $S3A1) and ($S3A1 !== $S2A1)){
        $msg = '04';    
    }

}
```

Comment: FYI: `$(function(){})`, `$(document).ready(function(){})` the former is the same as the latter, only need to use one of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matt... answering this specific part:

> It isn't till I refresh the page that it updates.

... I would say to make sure when you click the button to save your data, to also have a piece of JS code to update the labels on screen that you want to have the updated username if the response from server was successful.

Maybe something like this?

```
var updatedUsernameValue = $('#your_username_input').val();
$('.labels_to_update_with_new_username').html(updatedUsernameValue)
```

Comment: Hey Jorge, thanks for answering. I have yet to implement this into my code as I'm not quite sure I follow what is meant to go in the `labels_to_update_with_new_username`

Comment: I'm assuming you have `<label class="username"><?php echo $username?></label>` in some places. You could update those labels when you save the new username with javascript, `$('.username').val(updatedUsernameValue)`. Now for `updatedUsernameValue` you could get it from the input where the user typed the updated value: `var updatedUsernameValue = $('.new_username_input').val()`

Comment: I'm not using any labels at the moment just the textbox value to display what it is currently saved as. However, if you think this would be a better method perhaps this is the way forward. As I tried giving the submit buttons a onclick save() function where it set the textbox value to the php saved value but unfortunately it simple overwrote it.